# Finding the Laplace Transformation of $|t-1|$ (absolute value)

Tags: laplace-transform

I am unsure how to find the Laplace Transformation to this. I tried breaking the limit from $0$-infinity up, but it did not help.

Comment: How did breaking the interval of integration up not help?

Comment: This looks like another post from Michael, with a "newly created account"

Answer (score 3):

When $t \in [0,1]$, $|t-1| = 1-t$; otherwise, it is $t-1$.  The LT is then

$$\hat{f}(s) = \int_0^1 dt \: (1-t) e^{-s t} + \int_1^{\infty} dt \: (t-1) e^{-s t}$$

Use the fact that

$$\int dt \: t\,e^{-s t} = -\frac{e^{-s t} (s \,t+1)}{s^2}$$

so that

$$\hat{f}(s) =\frac{1-2 e^{-s}}{s} + \frac{2(s+1) e^{-s}-1}{s^2}  = \frac{1}{s} + \frac{2 e^{-s}-1}{s^2}$$

Comment: i was thinking it like this.thanks .+1

Comment: I did it this way, and ended up with [-3e^(-s)+1]/(s^2)+1/s. But this isn't the correct answer. I am unsure, where I went wrong.

Comment: @BlakeJacobs: That info would have been very helpful when you posted the question - I cannot read minds.  Anyway, you likely made a sign error or something, which is very common in problems involving absolute values.